# How do I uninstall Docker or remove the Docker directory?

Tags: docker

I am trying to learn Docker and have installed it on my laptop.  I have tried to uninstall it and delete the **Docker** directory as Administrator, but keep getting the error message **"The action cannot be completed because the file is open in Docker Desktop service"**.  But Docker Desktop Service is not open, and does not appear whenever I open Task Manager.  When I try to reinstall Docker, it says it it up to date, when clearly it is not.  I would appreciate any help getting a fresh installation of Docker.

Here is the **Docker** directory **C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker**.
[image]

Here is the error message.
[image]

Comment: Stop Docker service first and retry

Comment: How do I stop Docker Service?  I tried it from PowerShell, and the message I got conflicts with the previous error message I got.

PS C:\Users\029607> Stop-Service docker
Stop-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'docker'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Stop-Service docker
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (docker:String) [Stop-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand

Comment: If you have access to the windows machine, through UI, you can go to Start -> Services, and search for the Docker (probably is called Docker Desktop or something similar) service and manually Stop. You can also set the service to start Manually, not Automatically, give a restart and now docker is completely stopped and you can uninstall safely.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the windows machine, through UI, you can:

1. Go to *Start* -> *Services*, and search for the **Docker** (probably is called *Docker Desktop* or something similar) service and
2. Manually **Stop**. You can also set the service to start Manually, not Automatically, give a restart and
3. Now Docker is completely stopped and
4. You can **uninstall** safely.

Answer (score -1):

User azbarcea answered the question.

Comment: If someone answered your question you should give it an upvote, and click the checkmark to mark it as the answer you went with. This isn't a message board with a thread structure, it's a specific Q & A format.

Comment: it wasn't answered (but in comment) when @PyNerd created this answer. It was well intended.